# Dynamic Drop-down for Country & State in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

How to render options inside select tag in ReactJs?

I have a json data for country and state. I want to render states in select tag dynamically with selected country.

```
const onCountryChange = value => {
    const country = value.split("_")[0];
    const countryCode = value.split("_")[1];
    const countryId = value.split("_")[2];
    setCountry(country);
    setCountryCode(countryCode);
    setCountryId(countryId)
  };
```

Select tag for country

```
<select value={country} onChange={e => onCountryChange(e.target.value)}>
     <option value="" disabled>Select Country</option>
     {
         COUNTRIES.map((country, index) => {
                            return (
                              <option
                                key={index}
                                value={country.name + "_+" + country.phoneCode + "_" + country.id}
                              >
                                {country.name}
                              </option>
                            );
                          })
     }
</select>
```

Select tag for state

```
<select value={state} onChange={e => onStateChange(e.target.value)} >
     <option value="" disabled>Select State/Province</option>
     {
       STATES.filter(states => (states.country_id === countryId)).map((state, index) => {
                            console.log(state.name)
                            return (
                              <option
                                key={index}
                                value={state.name + "_+" + state.id}
                              >
                                {state.name}
                              </option>
                            );
                          })
     }                          
</select>
```

Drop down for country is rendering correctly. When I select a country, corresponding states are not rendering in select tag where as states are displayed in console.

Comment: I would guess that because you are using `index` as key React is avoiding rewrites where it can. Rather use `key={state.id}`. Per the docs: We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key. If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys. [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: I did change key to state.id but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code I can't answer your question exactly, but I have provided a basic working snippet that uses a simple re-usable `Select` component and stores the ids of the selected country and state using `useState`.

Also, there are some significant inefficiencies in your code that if you address will make everything more readable and may help avoid or more easily find errors in behavior or output.

Firstly, you have a great deal of duplication in writing two separate `select` elements which you have further complicated by returning from within them. This is a great time to abstract to a separate component.

```
function Select({ options, value, title, handleSelectChange }) {

  return (
    <select name="title" value={value ? value : ''} onChange={handleSelectChange} >
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>{title}</option>
      {options.map(option =>
        <option key={option.id} value={option.id}  >
          {option.name}
        </option>
      )}
    </select>
  )
}
```

Next, you are declaring an anonymous function in `onChange` to call a named function and only passing the `event`. Named functions in React can be called by direct reference and they will be passed the event intrinsically so you could simplify you code thus:

```
const onCountryChange = (event) => {
   console.log(event.target.value);
...
}

<select ... onChange={onCountryChange}>
```

Within `onCountryChange` there is again a lot of duplication (and three calls to `split` the same string). You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to simplify this

```
const onCountryChange = (e) => {
    const [country, countryCode, countryId] = e.target.value.split("_");
}
```

These are small pointers, but learning the basics and coding as cleanly as possible will help avoid tangles.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="App"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  const { useState} = React;

const countries = [
  { id: 'AD', name: 'Andorra' },
  { id: 'AE', name: 'United Arab Emirates' },
  { id: 'AF', name: 'Afghanistan' },
  { id: 'AG', name: 'Antigua and Barbuda' },
  { id: 'AI', name: 'Anguilla' },
]

const states = [
  { id: 'ad1', name: 'AD: State 1', countryId: 'AD' },
  { id: 'ad2', name: 'AD: State 2', countryId: 'AD' },
  { id: 'ad3', name: 'AD: State 3', countryId: 'AD' },
  { id: 'st1', name: 'AI: State 4', countryId: 'AI' },
  { id: 'st2', name: 'AI: State 5', countryId: 'AI' },
  { id: 'st3', name: 'AI: State 6', countryId: 'AI' },
  { id: 'ag1', name: 'AG: State 7', countryId: 'AG' },
  { id: 'ag2', name: 'AG: State 8', countryId: 'AG' },
  { id: 'ag3', name: 'AG: State 9', countryId: 'AG' },
  { id: 'af1', name: 'AF: State 10', countryId: 'AF' },
  { id: 'af2', name: 'AF: State 11', countryId: 'AF' },
  { id: 'af3', name: 'AF: State 12', countryId: 'AF' },
  { id: 'ae1', name: 'AE: State 13', countryId: 'AE' },
  { id: 'ae2', name: 'AE: State 14', countryId: 'AE' },
  { id: 'ae3', name: 'AE: State 35', countryId: 'AE' }
]

function Select({ options, value, title, handleSelectChange }) {

  return (
    <select name="title" value={value ? value : ''} onChange={handleSelectChange} >
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>{title}</option>
      {options.map(option =>
        <option key={option.id} value={option.id}  >
          {option.name}
        </option>
      )}
    </select>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [selectedCountryId, setSelectedCountryId] = useState(null);
  const [selectedStateId, setSelectedStateId] = useState(null);

  const handleCountryChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedStateId(null);
    setSelectedCountryId(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleStateChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedStateId(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
  <div>
    <div className="select-container">
      <Select 
        options={countries} 
        value={selectedCountryId} 
        title='Select Country' 
        handleSelectChange={handleCountryChange} 
      />
      <Select 
        options={states.filter(state => 
        state.countryId === selectedCountryId)} 
        value={selectedStateId} 
        title='Select State/Province'
        handleSelectChange={handleStateChange} 
      />
    </div>
    <div class='output'>
      <p>Selected Country Id: {selectedCountryId}</p>
      <p>Selected State Id: {selectedStateId}</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  )

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('App'));

 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out code duplication. I have followed suggested approach. I have created separate component for ```select``` element and used it in parent component. Countries are rendering but states did not render. I could see state names in console though. PS: my code looks exactly similar as your snippet.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Without seeing your code I can't say why it isn't working. The above snippet works, perhaps you can try comparing step by step (even if it isn't identical) to find where you are deviating?

Comment: I forgot to mention earlier. States are rendering when I remove filter functionality. But with this all states be available in dropdown.

Comment: well that is where you are going wrong then, make sure that your filter function is working outside of the loop, and that it is properly referencing the `countryID` stored in state.

Comment: I double checked it, everything is correct. I don't know why states are not rendering. I could see states changing in console with change in country.

Comment: if you want to post sandbox, or post your code here as it stands I can look, but otherwise I can't offer more.