# Javascript loop through JSON with nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm having trouble looping through JSON with nested array. Below are some snippets of my codes:

My JSON for first dropdown menu:

```
[
  {
    "Value": "Europe",
    "Name": "Europe"
  },
  {
    "Value": "Asia",
    "Name": "Asia"
  }
]
```

My JSON for second dropdown menu:

```
[
    {
        "Europe": [
            "UK",
            "Spain",
            "Netherland",
            "Germany"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Asia": [
            "Japan",
            "Korea",
            "China",
            "India"
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to append the values in these JSON into dropdown menu in my page. There are 2 dropdown menu. Second dropdown menu will populate based on the selected value of the first dropdown menu. I can append the value of the first dropdown menu but I'm having trouble with the second.

.CSHTML snippet:

```
<div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Continent:</label>
                    <select asp-for="@Model.first_value" id="continent" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Country:</label>
                    <select asp-for="@Model.second_value" id="country" class="form-control">
                        <option disabled selected></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Below are my scripts to append the first JSON:

```
let continentDropdown = document.getElementById('continent');
fetch(//my json url)
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                            response.status);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Examine the text in the response  
                    response.json().then(function (data) {
                        let option;

                        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            option = document.createElement('option');
                            option.text = data[i].Name;
                            option.value = data[i].Value;
                            continentDropdown.add(option);
                        }
                    });
                }
            )
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.error('Fetch Error -', err);
            });
```

So how do I append the second JSON to the second dropdown menu?

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add the markup here?

Comment: Is this vanilla? or are you using a framework (React, Vue, Angular...). Here is an almost identical question for React [dynamic-drop-down-for-country-state-in-reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63834854/dynamic-drop-down-for-country-state-in-reactjs/63838664#63838664)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was away on weekend. This is vanilla.